# OpenVpn from C# - Weird Timeout

Tags: c#, openvpn

i am trying to start OpenVpn from my C# Windows Service. Basically like this:

```
VpnProcess = new Process();
VpnProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "<Path to openvpn.exe in Program dir>";
VpnProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "--config " + "<vpnConfigName>" + " --log vpn.log";
VpnProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
VpnProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
VpnProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
VpnProcess.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = <Program dir>;
VpnProcess.Start();
```

so far so good, here is the resulting log:

```
Tue Sep 01 11:01:15 2015 OpenVPN 2.3.8 x86_64-w64-mingw32 [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [PKCS11] [IPv6] built on Aug  4 2015
Tue Sep 01 11:01:15 2015 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.1p 9 Jul 2015, LZO 2.08
Tue Sep 01 11:01:16 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Tue Sep 01 11:01:16 2015 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Tue Sep 01 11:01:16 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]217.79.181.93:1194
Tue Sep 01 11:01:16 2015 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]217.79.181.93:1194, sid=a7a52cba 93615557
Tue Sep 01 11:01:16 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=<censored>
Tue Sep 01 11:01:16 2015 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Tue Sep 01 11:01:16 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=<censored>, ST=<censored>, L=<censored>, O=<censored>, OU=<censored>, CN=<censored>, name=<censored>, emailAddress=<censored>
Tue Sep 01 11:02:16 2015 [<censored>] Inactivity timeout (--ping-restart), restarting
Tue Sep 01 11:02:16 2015 SIGUSR1[soft,ping-restart] received, process restarting
Tue Sep 01 11:02:16 2015 Restart pause, 2 second(s)
Tue Sep 01 11:02:18 2015 Socket Buffers: R=[8192->8192] S=[8192->8192]
Tue Sep 01 11:02:19 2015 UDPv4 link local: [undef]
Tue Sep 01 11:02:19 2015 UDPv4 link remote: [AF_INET]217.79.181.93:1194
Tue Sep 01 11:02:19 2015 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]217.79.181.93:1194, sid=4963868b 6f0eecb7
Tue Sep 01 11:02:20 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=<censored>
Tue Sep 01 11:02:20 2015 VERIFY OK: nsCertType=SERVER
Tue Sep 01 11:02:20 2015 VERIFY OK: depth=0, C=<censored>, ST=<censored>, L=<censored>, O=<censored>, OU=<censored>, CN=<censored>, name=<censored>, emailAddress=<censored>
Tue Sep 01 11:02:21 2015 Data Channel Encrypt: Cipher 'BF-CBC' initialized with 128 bit key
[...]
Tue Sep 01 11:02:28 2015 Initialization Sequence Completed
```

So, vpn hangs after VERIFY, then restarts itself, then its working fine. If i start openvn via cmd or Powershell with the exact same conditions and params, it connects successfully in the first try.

I spent several days trying to find out why this happens, no success. I tried all sensible combinations of StartInfo-Properties and checked whether the executing user changes after the soft restart. Nope, both times it's LocalSystem.

Answer (score 2):

Cause: server time was 1 minute ahead of time. So the freshly downloaded certificate on client was 'from the future', leading to rejection by the server. Server log showed this, but never client log

Answer (score 0):

Check your OpenVPN config file do you have option 'auth-nocache'.
I got a similar effect when I've added this option to client configuration. I use username / password to authenticate.